# How to Make Form w/ No underlying DB Table - APEX 19.2

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Very noob question, but how can I create a form in APEX that is not based on a database table?

For example, I am looking to create a "Change Password" form that consists of 3 fields:

- `USERNAME` (display only, value populated with `&APP_USER.` from URL)
- `NEW_PSWD`
- `CONFIRM_PSWD`

None of these fields will be saved to the database, so not sure how to handle the `SOURCE` for the underlying form. My first thought was to just use a SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT '' as username, 
       '' as new_pswd, 
       '' as confirm_pswd 
  FROM DUAL;
```

Is there a better / more APEX way to handle this?

**UPDATE:** I understand how to set up a process to handle the logic, but more asking what should I select for the SOURCE? It "yells" at me if I  select a TYPE (TABLE/VIEW, SQL QUERY, PLSQL FUNCTION BODY...) and do not put something in there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use "Form" page type. Pick "Blank" instead.

Then

- create a region on it
- put any number of items (3 in your case)
- create a button
- create a process which will fire when you press that button

  - it should do "smart" things in the database - insert user into a table, change their password, whatever you plan to do

Comment: I do not see a `Blank` option under the `Identification` section of the "form". Can I change the Type of the Region from `Form` to `Static Content`?

Update: just reread, your comment you were talking about the actual page type, not region type. Now I understand. I got it to work changing to `Static Content`, but is it better to just make a new page as Blank? Will I run into any problems down the road using `Static Content`?  (Thanks again for your help)

Comment: I think that whichever option you choose (between those two), you'll get the same result. The main point here is that there shouldn't be any table involved.

Comment: OK thanks again. Assuming one cannot change the page type once it is created, correct? I would have to create a new page to switch from "Form" to "Blank"?

Comment: No need to create a new page - the page type doesn't matter after it has been created. For example: you can make create a page of type region, remove the region and add a form and it will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks @KoenLostrie. So it is more like predefined page settings based on what you select more than being different page objects. Makes sense...much appreciated.